# Добавление пунктов Toolbar в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, menu, actionbar, toolbar

Есть фрагмент, в котором установлен тулбар и кнопка "назад" с ее обработкой (вне данного примера кода).

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarMainFrag);
activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();

//подключаем тулбар
activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//ставим кнопку на тулбар
activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//определяем две иконки для этой кнопки
iconToolbarSave = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_save_icon);
iconToolbarBack = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);

//ставим ярлык "назад"
activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(iconToolbarBack);
```

Каким образом можно программно добавить другие пункты меню в виде ярлыков?

Пробовал через `inflate menu.xml`, добавления кода не решает проблемы - иконка не появляется:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu_mainfragment, menu);
}
```

toolbar_menu_mainFragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/icon_info"
        android:title="Info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        />
</menu>
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что тулбаровское меню "собирается" либо через код, либо через макет? Как всё таки правильно добавлять иконки?

Comment: При добавление меню из фрагмента надо прописать в нём `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо большое, получилось :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При добавление меню из фрагмента надо прописать в нём `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`